# Show string constant for a group having multiple values

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, aggregate

I have a view `myview` which retrieves information in the following manner:

```
ID  | ATTRNAME | ATTRVAL
1   | attr1    | a
2   | attr2    | b
3   | attr3    | c
4   | attr3    | d
..  | ..       | ..
..  | ..       | ..
```

I need the output as follows:

```
ATTRNAME | ATTRVAL
attr1    | a
attr2    | b
attr3    | Multiple Values
```

Where, if there is a single value for an attribute (ATTRNAME), it should be displayed and if there are multiple values for an attribute (e.g., attr3), the text "Multiple Values" should be displayed.

I have tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT attrname
       , CASE cnt
            WHEN 1 THEN TO_CHAR(attrval)
            ELSE 'Multiple Values'
         END AS attrval_rev
FROM   myview
JOIN   (SELECT   attrname, COUNT(attrval) AS cnt
        FROM     myview
        GROUP BY attrname) USING (attrname)
```

This works, but this is not the right kind of solution as it is taking over 8 minutes to execute for about 11,000 rows. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way more simple:

```
SELECT ATTRNAME,
       CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = 1 THEN MIN(attrval) ELSE 'Multiple Values' END
 FROM myview
GROUP BY ATTRNAME
```

Let me know if you are still having performance issues.

Comment: Is string or values c and d should be displayed? Probably this question is for Rachcha.

Comment: @gustavodidomenico- please do not change anything. I think I was a bit confused and did not see the string in Rachcha's example. Your example is perfect.

Comment: But it was wrong, I was display the attribute name in place of the attribute value :). Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
select attrname,
       (case when min(attrval) = max(attrval) then min(attrval)
             when min(attrval) is null then null
             else 'Multiple Values'
        end)
from myview
group by attrname
```

Note that this ignores `NULL` as a valid value.

You can also do the first list as `when count(distinct attrval) = 1`, but `count(distinct)` is a bit more expensive than `min()` and `max()`.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT attrname, WHEN count(*) > 1 THEN 'Multiple Values' ELSE TO_CHAR(attrval) END 
FROM myview
GROUP BY attrname

Comment: You would have to include TO_CHAR(attrval) in your GROUP BY here and it would return the wrong result.